# api returning a string instead of JSON, how can I make my app use a string instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native

I am making some minor tweaks on an app that I haven't build (React Native).

an API call is returning a string while the app is expecting a Json, how can I change the app to accept that string instead ?

```
  const results = await resp.json()
```

Comment: `await resp.text()`

Comment: Assuming you're getting `resp` by using `fetch`, you can get a very good explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: If you want to get a string from JSON
You are using this function
JSON.stringify (result)